# MOXy unmarshalled bean from @PUT is null, depending on JSON property order

Tags: json, jersey, unmarshalling, moxy

I have a bean that is not unmarshalling, but there is no error message-- the endpoint is instead called with a null instance of the bean.

This is Jersey 2.22.1, with its default JAXB provider (MOXy).

I've reproduced the problem with a very simple bean:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Expense {
    private BigDecimal units;
    private BigDecimal unitRate;

    public BigDecimal getUnits() {
        return units;
    }
    public void setUnits(BigDecimal units) {
        this.units = units;
    }
    public BigDecimal getUnitRate() {
        return unitRate;
    }
    public void setUnitsRate(BigDecimal unitRate) {
        this.unitRate = unitRate;
    }
}
```

The `PUT` method of the resource:

```
public class ExpenseResource {
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response putExpense(Expense e) {
        if (e == null) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Failed to marshall expense object");
        }
        return TAEUtil.buildPutResponse(uriInfo, "/expenses/%d", this.expenseID);
    }

    //....
}
```

When `HTTP PUT` is sent ExpenseResource.putExpense IS called but the entire bean argument is often set to null. I don't get any exception or logged error.

It seems to depend on the JSON properties and their order. Specifically, the following JSON does *not* unmarshall:

```
{  "units": null, "unitRate": null }
```

But if I swap the two properties, unmarshalling works!

```
{  "unitRate": null, "units": null }
```

Testing reveals the following:

1. As long as unitRate isn't the last property of the JSON, Expense unmarshalls correctly.
2. If unitRate is the final property but is not set to null, Expense unmarshalls BUT unitRate itself does not (its null). Example:
   {  "units": 5, "unitRate": 5 }
3. Note that "units" is also a BigDecimal but unmarshalls correctly when last, and when not null. Yet I can see no difference between the two properties.
4. Adding a bogus final property makes no difference.

   { "units": 8, "unitRate": null, "zzz": "" } // fails

Despite isolating the behavior to this one field I don't have any explanation or workaround. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Updated with new information. The format of the JSON seems to be triggering the problem. More soon..

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem with a much simpler example, so I rewrote the question.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of my problem is a typo on the setter for unitRate. It should be "setUnitRate" not "setUnitsRate".

Normally that would simply cause unitRate to not get set when unmarshalling (as we see in test #2 above.) Simple enough to find and fix. But there appears to be a bug in this version of MOXy where if the last property of the JSON doesn't match any properties of the bean, AND it's null, then MOXy will give you null instead of your otherwise valid bean.

```
{ "units": 1, "someBogusString": null }  // fails

{ "units": 1, "someBogusString": 0 } // succeeds
```

I'll file it as an EclipseLink bug, see what they think of it.